# Behind Offset Sliding Menu

Tags: android, xml, slidingmenu

I'm using jfeinstein10's sliding menu.
I have the following xml code:

```
<com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_in"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
sliding:viewBehind="@layout/activity_main"
sliding:viewAbove= "@layout/slidingcontent"
sliding:touchModeAbove="fullscreen"
sliding:selectorEnabled="true"
sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/slidingmenu"
/>
```

@dimen I made a new dimension with the value of 100px:

```
     <dimen name = "slidingmenu">100px</dimen>
```

However when I run the project the sliding menu covers the entire screen.
It works if I put the following line in onCreate:

`getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100)`

How can I specify the entire layout in xml?

Comment: Why don't you use dp instead?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a xml file named "dimens" stored in "values" folder.

```
<resources>

<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="slidingmenu_offset">160dp</dimen>
<dimen name="list_padding">10dp</dimen>
<dimen name="shadow_width">5dp</dimen>

<integer name="num_cols">1</integer>
</resources>
```

Then you can use your code as follow:

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
```